# How to make a global variable for all blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel, global-variables

Good Peoples.

I have an issue with my project.

In the layout blade, I need to fetch some data from the database. But I cannot pass variables as there has no route for the layout blade. It's just a master blade.

Is there any way to make a global variable and use it all blade?

Thanks for the valuable replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to have global functions or variables there are different ways
in my opinion, the easiest way is:

make a helper php file to restore global functions and vars, in this way you
load this file in composer.json and you can call that everywhere you want.

I created Functions.php in App/Helpers directory to restore my global vars and functions.

after that declare the file in composer.json:
"autoload", inside it if there is not "files(array)" add it and set the path to
your file. in my example, it is "app/Helpers/Functions.php".

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/Functions.php"
        ]
    },
```

[image]

finally, rerun the

```
php artisan serve
```

for accessing a variable in your blade, I'm not sure you can do it or not (I tried but it returns undefined variable).

you can do:

```
// in your helper file
myFunc() {
    $myVar = 'value';
    return $myVar;
}

// in your blade
{{ myFunc() }}
```

or using classes:

```
// in your helper file
class myClass {
    protected $myVar = 'value';
    protected static $staticVar = 'value';

    public myFunc() {
        return $this->myVar;
    }

    public static staticFunc() {
        return myClass::$staticVar;
    }
}

// in your blade
{{ (new myClass())->myFunc() }}
// of static function
{{ myClass::staticFunc() }}
```

hope, it helps...

Comment: Yes I can get the data in controller. But how can I use that in layout blade. As my layout blade has no route.

Comment: I added completed guide

Answer (score 0):

you can use laravel helpers to declare a global variable, you can create your own customize helper function.
you can follow [laravel custom helpers](https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers) and this one to custom [create helpers](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-laravel-helper--cms-28537)

Answer (score 0):

[Create a new Service Provider as suggested in here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#passing-data-to-views)

Add your new Service Provider to the configuration file (config/app.php).

In the boot method of your new Service Provider use:

View::share( 'something_cool', 'this is a cool shared variable' );
Now you are ready to use $something_cool in all of your views.